# SAS concatenation operator using date macro

Tags: sql, sas

I´m getting these two macros over a date prompt:
date_min=01Jan2014 and date_max=.....

Now i need to put the macros in this format

```
'01JAN2014'
```

I tried it with

```
"'"||&datepromptest_min||"'"
```

but i get this:

```
"'"||01Jan2014||"'"
```

I know that the || work with normal variables, but with &macros this step dont work...anybody an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing this:

```
%let olddate = 01jan2014;
%let newdate = %unquote(%quote(%'&olddate%'));
```

The `%unquote` removes any macro quoting applied by `%quote`, which in turn allows you to mask the single quotes and resolve the macro variable between them. Without doing this you might notice unexpected behaviour when using `&newdate` in downstream code.

If double quotes are acceptable, you could also do:

```
%let newdate = %sysfunc(quote(&olddate));
```

Comment: Thank you very much user667489 for the sample and the explanation...it works!

Answer (score 1):

This is because anything related to macro variables or macro are executed first and everything else is executed later. We have to be always careful while using macro variables along with any other code because of execution order.  Use call symput for your desired requirement as shown below.

```
 %let datepromptest_min = 01JAN2014;
 data _null_;
 call symput('datepromptest_min', "'"||"&datepromptest_min"||"'");
 run;

 %put value of &datepromptest_min;
```

in log it shows as

```
value of '01JAN2014'
```